# Can other players see signal messages in the lobby?

Tags: splatoon-3

When I'm in a lobby waiting for a match to start I'll often send Booyah [signal messages](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Signal) to the other players waiting with me. However, I've never seen a player Booyah back to me. That has me wondering: can other players in the lobby see my signal messages?

[image: booyahing in the lobby]

Comment: While I don't know for sure, this feels very odd. Either they simply don't do it, or it's actually a bug. I can't think of a reason to implement this, then not transmitting it. Could it be a range dependent thing? You're rather far off I'd say.

Comment: I've used signals when directly next to players before. There also isn't a range limit when using signals in battles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they don't, I just tried with some friends.
But they do see your character doing the "booyah" pose.